# Model Fomset and deletion

Tags: django, modelform, formset

I have created a modelformset usign modelformset_factory

```
formfactory = modelformset_factory(HasJobs, form=HasJobsModelForm, can_delete=True)
formset = modelformset_factory(request.POST or None)

if request.method == "POST":
    form = AccountModelForm(request.POST, instance=account)
    account = form.save()
    for job_form in formset:
        instance = job_form.save(commit=False)
        instance.account = account
        instance.save()
```

In other words I create an account using each model form and then I create each Instance of HasJob using each form in the formset and save it after setting the account property of the instance to the above saved account. But when I click on the delete button of each form in the formset on the template, form is posted normally but no deletion. Why is that?

EDIT: changing code in to this inside if

```
account=form.save()
formset.save()
```

leads to the deletion of an instance but not in saving when creating a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the `formset.deleted_forms`:

```
for form in formset.deleted_forms:
    if form.instance.pk:
        form.instance.delete()
```

As alternative you can check for `DELETE` key in the `cleaned_data`:

```
for job_form in formset:
    if job_form.is_valid():
        if job_form.cleaned_data.get('DELETE') and job_form.instance.pk:
            job_form.instance.delete()
        else:
            instance = job_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.account = account
            instance.save()
```

Comment: No i'm using 1.6 django. Can it be done in 1.6?It says that modelformset handles the deletion itself when save is called. But It won't delete